# PHP Considers my absolute path a relative one

Tags: php

Currently I have PHP 7.2 installed and I was trying to get spatie/image-optimizer to work but somehow it considers my literal paths as non existent ones. If I give it the following path:

> /data/www/**MY DOMAIN**/images/thumbnails/700/615/detailed/1/83-221-343-V01.jpg

It will output the following:

> 2018/07/13 14:44:26 [error] 18931#18931: *3749 FastCGI sent in stderr:
>
> "PHP message: PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught InvalidArgumentException:
>
> /data/www/**MY DOMAIN**/images/thumbnails/700/615/detailed/1/83-221-343-V01.jpg
>
> does not exist in
>
> /data/www/**MY DOMAIN**/app/addons/theme/lib/vendor/spatie/image-optimizer/src/Image.php:14

But if I check the directory I can confirm that the file is there with the correct permissions.

Any ideas?

Comment: Why do you even give such a path?

Comment: Please post the code that produces this error, otherwise it's a guessing game.

Comment: In what way is it "considering your absolute path a relative one"?  The title and description of the problem aren't making any sense to me, it just looks like it can't read the file and that's all.

Comment: I can't see anything in that error message suggesting it is interpreting the path as relative: the first path mentioned is exactly as you entered it, and the second is telling you where in the code the check happened.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just looked at the Image class on Github. Here's where the exception is thrown.

```
public function __construct(string $pathToImage)
{
    if (! file_exists($pathToImage)) {
        throw new InvalidArgumentException("`{$pathToImage}` does not exist");
    }
    $this->pathToImage = $pathToImage;
}
```

A good way of checking you have it properly set is to use `realpath()`

Realpath creates absolute paths from relative ones, returning false if the path doesn't exist.

```
$path = __DIR__ .'/../../something'; // (imagine __DIR__ is /some/random/path to begin with)
echo $path; // outputs /some/something
```

You can also check in your terminal simply by typing:

```
ls /path/to/image.jpg
```

If it lists, it does indeed exist and shouldn't throw an error.

Comment: Well, about 10 minutes after I posted this question it magically started to work, and I dont have the faintest idea how.

Answer (score 0):

Switch to the user your php is running as and try to access the file. It could be that you are missing the execute permissions on one of the folders on the way to the file.

Comment: `file_exists()` would still return true regardless of execute rights.